# Can't run antd locally

Tags: antd

Steps:

npm i
npm start

[server starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpI5s.png)

Open http://localhost:8001/
[error image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNnUL.png)

[error image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doN6X.jpg)

OS: MacOS 12.0.1 (21A559) M1

Can you help me with this problem? Looks like some problem with css build.

Comment: Hello, please provide a [mrc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question in order to obtain better assistance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't run antd library in development mode, I run dev server, but it doesn't work. You can see the error in the attached screenshot. This instruction doesn't work for me https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/wiki/Development